# How to generate an unique (10 characters) ID in PHP

Tags: php, unique, generator

How to generate a unique (10 characters) ID in PHP, and **most importantly** how to get notified that the unique ID generator can't generate unique ID's anymore (due to it has already generated all the possible unique IDs').

Comment: If you use a mix of letters and numbers, you'll practically never run out, there are 3x10^15 combinations. And if you use both uppercase and lowercase, that increases it to 8x10^17.

Comment: @Barmar can you please explain it as an example?

Comment: generating unique ids is easy and unlimited by design. You may then code any kind of logic to impose limits upon it, and notify by whatever means when you choose to enforce the limit.

Comment: If you use letters and digits, that's 36 possibilities for each character. With 10 characters, the total number is 36^10 = 3x10^15.

Comment: Does it have to be 10 digits? PHP has a built-in `uniqid` function that generates a 13 or 23 digit ID.

Comment: @Barmar but I find this ```This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value.``` in the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Comment: It will be unique as long as the clock doesn't go backwards.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your reply.
I know that uniqid function, but i am thinking that could also run out (can be duplicated)

Comment: It's based on the time. So unless the clock goes backward, you won't get the same result. And if you add the `more_entropy` argument, it adds additional random digits so that if the clock part repeats, the additional ones won't likely match.

Comment: @Barmar Ah thanks I figured it out :).
but lemme know why that function (uniqid) does not guarantee uniqueness of return value?

Answer (score 0):

this function will generate a random string of the $length using the characters supplied in $charset (default upper and lower case alpha numeric)

```
function rand_str($length, $charset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') {
    $result = '';
    $count = strlen($charset);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $result .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count - 1)];
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(rand_str(10)); // generate 10 character random string
```

NOTE: you'll need to store generated strings somewhere if you need to check uniqueness - in a db perhaps?

Comment: This doesn't guarantee uniqueness, but the chance of collisions will be very low.

Comment: I will try this and Let you know. thank you Wee Zel :)

Comment: @WeeZel
What is the initial value of $length?

Comment: @S.Simith you need to pass $length to the function, it's the length of the random string you want. see https://eval.in/871500. in your case you want 10 characters so use 10.